# KineticJS .toImage() proper method for creating image from region / group

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs

When using the .toImage() method in KineticJS, I always seem to get a much larger image than is really necessary, with the piece I need taking up only the top left corner of the data image. My stage is scaled based on window size and a pre-defined initial size (on window resize, resize stage function called which sets the scale and the size of the container). Should I be setting some sort of crop when I use toImage() to compensate for this? Looking at the image, it seems that the overall image is about twice the size it needs to be, and the piece I need is about half the size I need, when the scale is at around 0.5 (the stage is about half size because I use Chrome and leave the developer bar open at the bottom for debugging).

Here's what I'm using now:

```
desc.toImage({
    width: sideW / cvsObj.scale,
    height: sideH / cvsObj.scale,
    callback: function(img) {
        desc.hide();
        sideImg.transitionTo({x : sideW / 2, width : 0, duration : 0.25, callback : function() {
            // add image to emulate content
            var params = {name : 'descimg', width : sideW, height : sideH, image : img, x : sideW / 2, y : 0};
            var image = new Kinetic.Image(params);
            side.add(image);
            image.setWidth(1);
            sideImg.hide();
            image.transitionTo({x : 0, width : sideW, duration : 0.25, callback : function() {
                side.add(desc);
                desc.show();
                image.hide();
                cvsObj.page.draw();
            }});
        }});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this question two and a half months ago, and received no replies until today. I've kept up-to-date with KineticJS - even adding my own bug reports and code suggestions. However, recently I revisited this particular section of code and came up with something a bit better - the image I'm getting back is now properly cropped and can be inserted as is into my canvas layers. Here's the code:

```
// grp = kinetic group, iw = image width, ih = image height, rimg = returned image array for a deferred function, cvsobj.scale is a global stage scale variable (i scale the stage to fit the window)
getImage : function(grp, iw, ih, rimg) {
    var dfr = $.Deferred();
    var gp = grp.getAbsolutePosition();
    grp.toImage({
        width: iw * cvsObj.scale,
        height: ih * cvsObj.scale,
        x : gp.x,
        y : gp.y,
        callback: function(img) {
            rimg.push(img);
            dfr.resolve(rimg);
        }
    });
    return dfr.promise();
}
```

This is an extended prototype function - part of a sub-section functionality for converting an entire layer or section of a layer into an image specifically for manipulating in an animation sequence. Hopefully this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

There have been improvements to KineticJs over time and functions work in a 'better' way nowadays. Try the new KineticJS 4.3:

```
 http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.3.0.min.js
```

Comment: I've been keeping relatively up-to-date with KineticJS. I'm currently running 4.2 because 4.3 would require a lot of code changes and nothing in the changelog refers to enhancements that we would benefit from. At this point in time we'd prefer not to have to go through the thousands of lines of javascript we've already written to make our code compatible without actually gaining much, if anything, from upgrading. I've since made changes to my code to get this working better. I'll post my own code so perhaps someone else will benefit.