# Adding Kinetic JS to PDF file

Tags: html, kineticjs, pdf.js

I'm trying to add KineticJS shapes to an **existing** pdf file using pdf.js. The problem I have is that KineticJS creates a new canvas and won't use the canvas created by pdf.js. I've tried referencing the pdf.js canvas in KineticJS but that won't work.  Any Ideas in how to integrate the two?  The main purpose is to provide annotations to the pdf.

Comment: well, the idea would be to save the Kinetic canvas as an image and then place that image in the pdf.js canvas. This may point you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13164226/kineticjs-toimage-proper-method-for-creating-image-from-region-group

Comment: I'm not sure that would be useful. I need to be able to edit the shapes later on. I also need to be able to see the pdf so that the placement of the shapes makes sense.

Comment: can you post the code that references the pdf.js canvas

Answer (score 0):

If you’re not too far into the process, you might try Bytescout which generates .pdf and also includes a hook to load your canvas image into your pdf.

Everything is done on the client-side, so you can view/edit/view/edit to your heart’s content.

They are here:  http://bytescout.com/products/developer/pdfgeneratorsdkjs/index.html (BTW, No sales pitch here--I’m not connected to bytescout in any way!)

Here’s an example from their website that shows an embedded canvas:

```
function CreatePDF() {

    // create BytescoutPDF object instance
    var pdf = new BytescoutPDF();

    // set document properties: Title, subject, keywords, author name and creator name
    pdf.propertiesSet("Sample document title", "Sample subject", "keyword1, keyword 2, keyword3", "Document Author Name", "Document Creator Name");

    // set page size
    pdf.pageSetSize(BytescoutPDF.A4);

    // set page orientation (BytescoutPDF.PORTRAIT = portrait, BytescoutPDF.LANDSCAPE = landscape)
    pdf.pageSetOrientation(BytescoutPDF.PORTRAIT);

    // add new page
    pdf.pageAdd();

    // create temporary canvas (you can also simply get existing canvas)
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    // set width and height
    canvas.width = 320;
    canvas.height = 240;

    // get context from canvas (to draw on)
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    // set white background color
    context.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    // and fill the background with white color
    context.fillRect(0, 0, 320, 240);

    // draw the yellow circle
    context.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    context.fillStyle = "#FFFF00";
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(100, 100, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    context.closePath();
    context.stroke();
    context.fill();

    // load image from canvas into BytescoutPDF
    pdf.imageLoadFromCanvas(canvas);

    // place this image at given X, Y coordinates on the page
    pdf.imagePlace(20, 40);


    // return BytescoutPDF object instance
    return pdf;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think BytescoutPDF works like JSPDF in that it creates a pdf from canvas content. I actually don't have that problem.  The problem is viewing an existing PDF (with pdf.js) and adding annotations to that PDF using KineticJS.